# How to restrict folder access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails app that writes to a file in my admins view folder. It creates a new folder for each user and a text file containing sensitive information.

How do i take the root folder and make sure no one can access the files inside?

```
/app/views/admin/NameOfFolder
```

NameOfFolder is the folder I want to protect that has sensitive data. The NameOfFolder is based on the user it is made for.

Comment: Just wanted to add I do understand now that this is not the best way of doing things. It does help to know the answer though to get a better understanding of how rails works in general. All the down vote hate makes me a sad panda.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to. Nobody can access anything in `/app`. Only files in `public` are directly accessible to the Internet.

That said, it's highly wrong to use flat files for data storage, and *especially* to contain sensitive information. It's also extremely wrong to write arbitrary *data* files into `/app/views`. That directory is for your *viwes*, not for data storage.

Comment: It is just to record their a history of check-outs and check-ins for inventory. However, if it is bad practice, what would be the best way to go about this? Also, thank you for the response!

Comment: @codingdraculasbrain A database, and an ActiveRecord model.

Comment: Too you can write this info into custom log file.